# Prevent views in relative layout from overlapping in spinner

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using this layout in a spinner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:mode="twoLine"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/text"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="right" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

When the first textviews contents get too long they overlap onto the 3rd textview.

I've tried

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:maxLines="2"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

on the first view which does nothing. I've also tried setting layout_tostartof to text3, setting layout_toleftof to text 3 which make my view disappear, likely off the spinner somehow.

Comment: Consider using `LinearLayout` and then set `layout_weight` property

Comment: Did you try setting text3 to be below text2 (using layout_below)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my layout to a TableLayout as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:mode="twoLine"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_column="44" />
    </TableRow>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/text"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

</TableLayout>
```